# Complex (or impossible) Select from mysql table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a `mysql`table like this:

```
Person     x     minutes     population
p1         F     3           p1p2p3p4
p2         B     1           p1p2p3p4
p1         B     7           p1p2p3
p3         F     2           p2p3p1
p1         F     3           p1p2
p1         B     4           p2p3p1
p2         C     3           p1p2p3
p2         B     1           p2p1p3
p2         F     7           p2p3p4
p3         B     2           p2p3p4
p1         F     3           p2p1p3p4
```

What I need to select, for each `Person` is:

1- Count the number of times x is equal to `F`;

2- Count the number of times x is equal to `B`;

3- Sum the value of `minutes`when the `person`appears in the variable `population`;

Then, the resulting `select`would be like this:

```
Person    nF    nB    tminutes
p1        3     2     24
p2        1     2     36
p3        1     1     33
```

I am not sure if this is even possible. I have tried something like:

```
SELECT 
 Person,
 sum(x='F') as nF,
 sum(x='B') as nB,
 sum(minutes) WHERE population IS LIKE '%Person%' as tminutes
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Person
```

Any ideas would be very welcome! Thanks.

Comment: A `SELECT` that appears to be nearly impossible usually is a tell-tale of bad database design. Relational databases are not glorified CSV containers. Build some actual relations and your SQL becomes much easier. Resolve the `population` column into something meaningful.

Comment: `population` has a meaning for me. It would be no problem to do: `SELECT sum(minutes) as tminutes FROM myTable WHERE population LIKE '%p2%'`.

Comment: I did not say it has no meaning for you. It has no meaning *for the database*. It represents a structure that your database design does not represent and that's why you can't use SQL (or *efficient* SQL, for that matter) to select from it.

Comment: Believe me I need the database to be like that. I don't require the SELECT to be very efficient, but to do the job.

Comment: Sorry, not buying it. The database ought to represent the relations between your data in its structure. And your `population` column clearly is either a sequence or a list of options, in other words it has an impied structure mashed into a string. That's like storing comma-separated values into a VARCHAR and then trying to do meaningful SQL on that. It ought to be moved to a separate table in a clean design. If it were in a separate table the SELECT you want to do would become trivial.

Comment: @Tomalak I would like to contact you and explain you what is my case, so probably you can give me an advice on how to proceed. Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147301/discussion-between-javi-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using a sub-select:

```
SELECT 
    Person,
    SUM(IF(x = 'F', 1, 0)) AS nF,
    SUM(IF(x = 'B', 1, 0)) AS nB,
    (SELECT SUM(minutes) FROM test_table WHERE INSTR(population, t1.Person) > 0) AS tminutes
FROM test_table t1
GROUP BY Person
```

The result of this query:

```
Person | nF | nB | tminutes
---------------------------
p1     | 3  | 2  | 27
p2     | 1  | 2  | 36
p3     | 1  | 1  | 33
```

Comment: This is not correct. The first two `nF` and `nB` are correct, although they could have been written in a more simply way (as in my question). The third variable `tminutes` does the same thing as if you write `sum(minutes) as tminutes`, and this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: see my update. there is also a mistake in your expected output: `p1` has `27` minutes not `24`.

Comment: Great. This works perfectly. I accept your answer now. As someone said, it is a bit inefficient, and it takes long time for big tables. Thank you!